# Recyclerview show data again and again when call function multiple times in firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Recntly I am working on android project with firebase, I am using recyclerview for showing data. I have added edittext and search button, when we click search button one function call and show its search relevant data. But issue is that when I click the search button it shows the data(suppose only 1 result found) when I click again search button it again append same data, and it shows again and again contineously when I click button.

I am really worried, kindly suggest me whats the issue.

My Adapter code

```
import android.app.LauncherActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Find_donor_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Find_donor_Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<find_donor_helper> find_donor_helper;

    public Find_donor_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<find_donor_helper> find_donor_helper) {
        this.context = context;
        this.find_donor_helper = find_donor_helper;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.find_blood_layout,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final find_donor_helper helper = find_donor_helper.get(position);
        holder.lname.setText(find_donor_helper.get(position).getFullname());
        holder.bldgrp.setText(find_donor_helper.get(position).getBloodgroup());

        final String n = helper.getPhonenumber();
        holder.lnumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try
                {
                    Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:03465987599"));
                    call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(call);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.ucall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                call.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"+n));
                call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(call);
            }
        });



        Picasso.get().load(helper.getUserimg()).into(holder.uimg);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return find_donor_helper.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView lname,bldgrp;
        Button lnumber,ucall;
        ImageView uimg;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            lname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            bldgrp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bloodgroup);
            lnumber = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            uimg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userimg);
            ucall = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.call);
        }
    }
}
```

main code

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Find_BloodDonator extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView findblood;
    ArrayList<find_donor_helper> arrayList;
    Find_donor_Adapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    EditText searchtext;
    String st;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find__blood_donator);

        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pd.setCancelable(false);


        findblood = findViewById(R.id.findblood);

        findblood.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        arrayList = new ArrayList<find_donor_helper>();

        //alldata("blooddonor","Yes");


        searchtext = findViewById(R.id.searchtext);
        st = searchtext.getText().toString();

        searchtext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                alldata("bloodgroup","hello");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                alldata("bloodgroup","hello");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                alldata("bloodgroup",s.toString());
            }
        });


    }

    private void alldata(String blooddonor,String bloodgroup) {

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        Query chk = reference.limitToLast(10).orderByChild(blooddonor).equalTo(bloodgroup);

        chk.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                pd.cancel();

                try {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        find_donor_helper donor_helper = dataSnapshot1.getValue(find_donor_helper.class);
                        arrayList.add(donor_helper);
                    }
                    adapter = new Find_donor_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
                    findblood.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    pd.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(Find_BloodDonator.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                pd.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(Find_BloodDonator.this, "Server error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Add the code of the search button on click function

Comment: @CyberShark I have added edittext function code

Comment: Recently I have changed the code...when editext text change function call and show the result...

Comment: instead of changing adapters each time the search text changes, try notifying dataset changed

Comment: I tried, but no luck. It shows duplicate :(

Comment: The pattern is to have a seperate class for data, which should query a data set provided to an adapter, rather than having the firebase commands inside the adapter. That way you can call notifyDataSetChanged or maybe swapAdapter commands. Another janky solution would be to clear the list everytime, but defeats the point lol

Comment: How I can clear list everytime, can you please suggest me how and where and what. Because I'm little bit newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a new search, your `onDataChange` gets called with all search results. Then you currently add those search results to `arrayList`, which means that as you execute additional searches, the list just keeps getting longer.

To only show the results of the latest query, you need to clear `arrayList` before adding the new search results to it:

```
Query chk = reference.limitToLast(10).orderByChild(blooddonor).equalTo(bloodgroup);

chk.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        pd.cancel();
        arrayList.clear()
        try {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                find_donor_helper donor_helper = dataSnapshot1.getValue(find_donor_helper.class);
                arrayList.add(donor_helper);
            }
            adapter = new Find_donor_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
            findblood.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            pd.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(Find_BloodDonator.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        pd.cancel();
        Toast.makeText(Find_BloodDonator.this, "Server error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

---

Note that you don't need to create a new adapter every time your change `arrayList`. You can also modify `arrayList` to contain the up-to-date items (as you already do), and then simply tell the existing adapter to refresh its view(s) with the updated data.

This means you can move the creation of the adapter to your `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find__blood_donator);

    ...

    arrayList = new ArrayList<find_donor_helper>();

    adapter = new Find_donor_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
    findblood.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And then to refresh the data:

```
Query chk = reference.limitToLast(10).orderByChild(blooddonor).equalTo(bloodgroup);

chk.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        pd.cancel();
        arrayList.clear()
        try {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                find_donor_helper donor_helper = dataSnapshot1.getValue(find_donor_helper.class);
                arrayList.add(donor_helper);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            pd.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(Find_BloodDonator.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        pd.cancel();
        Toast.makeText(Find_BloodDonator.this, "Server error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```